# Does React.useCallback memoize curried functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization

I use this pattern sometimes where I declare a curried function inside `useCallback`.

```
const Child = ({ handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick("foo")}>foo</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick("lorem")}>lorem</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const handleClick = useCallback(
    (newState) => () => {
      setState(newState);
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child handleClick={handleClick} />
      <p>{state}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit serene-platform-kuzc2]

because I want to pass arguments from JSX to the event handlers and to avoid multiple handlers.

When the component rerenders, `handleClick` will be called and the function that is returned will be assigned to the `onClick` prop, but will it be a new function every time or will the nested function also get memoized by `useCallback`?

PS: This is a simple example. Assume a `useCallback` usage with multiple dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit

Following answer refers to the [initial version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69144918/revisions) of the OP's code in which `handleClick` was not passed as a prop to `Child` component.

---

You don't really need `useCallback` in this case.

Actually, it would be better not to use the `useCallback` hook in this case because:

1. Callback function passed to `useCallback` is created everytime your component re-renders. As a result, a new function is getting created anyways, just like it would without the use of `useCallback`
2. Getting a memoized version of the `handleClick` function doesn't provides any benefit in your case. Memoization would be useful if `handleClick` is passed as a prop to child component(s).

> ...but will it be a new function every time or will the nested
> function also get memoized by useCallback?

No, the nested function won't be memoized.

`handleClick` is a memoized function but that memoized function returns a new function everytime it executes.

Invoking `handleClick` is just like invoking any other function - anything declared inside its body is created everytime it is invoked.

Comment: I used a simple example but imagine a `useCallback` with several dependencies

Comment: _Function passed to useCallback is created everytime your component re-renders_. Why, an empty array is passed as the second argument in the hook.

Comment: @RohitSharma empty dependency array doesn't prevents the callback function from being evaluated. A new function is created BUT `useCallback` will discard it and return a memoized function. `useCallback(() => {}, [])` is evaluated just like any other function invocation expression. Anonymous callback function is created everytime `useCallback` is invoked.

Comment: So, in a scenario where the buttons are in a child component and if the `handleClick` is passed as a prop, the only advantage we get is that the component wouldn't rerender because `handleClick` won't change. Is that correct?

Comment: @RameshReddy yes, exactly. If `handleClick` is added in the dependency array of `useCallback` or `useEffect` hook in child component(s), then memoized version of `handleClick` will prevent unnecessary execution of `useEffect` hook and unnecessary creation of a memoized function in child component(s).

Answer (score 0):

It should, either curry or not, it's a function instance, as long as you want to keep an old function instance, you can use it.

But don't use it because the prop `onClick`, because when your component renders, this `button` has to render regardless of the `onClick`. So your line can be simply as

```
  const onClick = value => () => { setState(value) }
```

Or you can even promote this to a global function.

```
  const handle = setState => value => () => { setState(value) }
```

NOTE: i don't want to say `useCallback` most of time is useless. But actually if you don't know why you want to use a `useMemo`, don't use a `useCallback`. They are designed to skip an assignment, but not designed to skip a render, or in your case, to improve reusability. (not for that purpose).